# AWS Image transfer to other cloud

Tags: linux, aws, disk-image

We have more than 5 instances AWS cloud, but I want to shift these instance image to other cloud is it possible?  if yes so please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

**Download instance SNAPSHOT and use that SNAPSHOT in your new Cloud.**

*if you are not on the same Cloud, and no provision to restore foreign instance automatically on their platform, then you can do the following:*

**Step 1 :**

Image your server hard disk using dd and ssh using to make exact copy of your server disk with option -C for compression;

#### Check your disk location:

```
techie@plab:~# lsblk -o name,type,size,mountpoint
    NAME  TYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT
    xvda1 disk   128M [SWAP]
    xvda2 disk   30G /

Or    
techieplab:~# df -h 
  Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev486M  4.0K  486M   1% /dev
    tmpfs99M  160K   99M   1% /run
    /dev/xvda2   30G  733M   28G   3% /
    none4.0K 0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    none5.0M 0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none495M 0  495M   0% /run/shm
    none100M 0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Note that we have our device (disk) located at `/dev/xvda2` with 30G space  this from `/dev/xvda`

**Copy the hard disk over ssh using with Compression :**

```
ssh -C root@your-server-ip "dd if=/dev/xvda bs 1M" | dd of=MyServerDisk-of-`date +%F`.iso
```

You will end up with a file similar to ***MyServerDisk-of-2017-08-31.iso***

**Step 2**

Provide this ***MyServerDisk-of-2017-08-31.iso*** on your new Cloud to load your Custom OS.